# How to write a pandas dataframe to .arrow file

Tags: pandas, apache-arrow

How can I write a pandas dataframe to disk in `.arrow` format?  I'd like to be able to read the arrow file into Arquero as demonstrated [here](https://observablehq.com/@uwdata/arquero-and-apache-arrow).

Answer (score 7):

Since Feather *is* the Arrow IPC format, you can probably just use `write_feather`. See http://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/feather.html

Comment: Interesting - I will try this.  I knew they were very similar!

Comment: Thank you.  I can confirm that `feather.write_feather(table, 'file.feather',  compression='uncompressed')` works with Arquero, as well as saving to `arrow` using
`pa.ipc.new_file`.  The uncompressed feather file is about 10% larger on disk than the `.arrow` file.    A compressed feather file cannot be read using the same methodology:
https://observablehq.com/d/298f76ea5f91b5fe
which is taken from 
https://observablehq.com/@uwdata/arquero-and-apache-arrow
I've uploaded the files here: https://github.com/RobinL/arrow_test

Comment: Correct, the JS implementation of Arrow hasn't added support for compressed feather/arrow files, so you'll need to write them uncompressed.

Comment: Cheers guys - couldn't find anything in the arrow docs, notebooks or mailing lists on this, is there anywhere? I'm assuming this is related to the lack of browser support for javascript compression/decompression.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this as follows:

```
import pyarrow
import pandas

df = pandas.read_parquet('your_file.parquet')

schema = pyarrow.Schema.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=False)
table = pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=False)

sink = "myfile.arrow"

# Note new_file creates a RecordBatchFileWriter 
writer = pyarrow.ipc.new_file(sink, schema)
writer.write(table)
writer.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Pandas** can directly write a DataFrame to the [binary Feather format.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_feather.html#pandas-dataframe-to-feather) (uses pyarrow)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
df.to_feather('my_data.arrow')
```

Additional keywords are passed to [pyarrow.feather.write_feather()](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.feather.write_feather.html#pyarrow.feather.write_feather). This includes the compression, compression_level, chunksize and version keywords.